# setTimeout unpredictable behavior in IE9

Tags: javascript, timer, internet-explorer-9, settimeout

I am looking at a third-party javascript that has a global timer.  The timer is used to warn the user with a modal alert box when the session is within 5 minutes of expiration, and any mouse-clicks or keystrokes will reset the timer.

The timer is set up during OnLoad.  I wanted to add a second timer, but I have noticed that if the second timer expires while the modal alert box is displayed, the behavior is unpredictable.  For sake of simplicity:

```
var myFunkyTimer1;
var myFunkyTimer2;

function myOnLoadFunction() {
  // alert in 10 seconds
  myFunkyTimer1 = setTimeout(function(){alert("Get Funky!")}, 10000);
  // alert immediately after user clicks ok
  myFunkyTimer2 = setTimeout(function(){alert("GET RANDOM!")}, 11000); 
}
```

This works fine in IE8.  However, in IE9 the first alert box displays 10 seconds after page load, but if I wait over one second to click OK, the second alert box will not display until sometime between 2-11 seconds afterward.

I can work around this issue, but I was curious if anyone had seen similar issues with setTimeout on IE9 and if Microsoft knows they are randomizing any timers that are queued up behind modal popup windows.

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, unless you want to use `eval`

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code to be more politically correct, although the original third-party code was using strings to invoke callbacks and not anonymous functions ... still results in the same random invocation of the second callback.

Comment: Actually, the second interval is *not* random.  Apparently, the browser attempts to handle the timeout, cannot handle the callback because of the modal window, and requeues the timer for the FULL duration.  So if I hit the OK button on the first alert at 12 seconds, then the second alert will go off 10 seconds later (11 + 11).  If I hit the OK button on the first alert at 23 seconds, then the second alert will go off 10 seconds later (11 + 11 + 11).  This is unexpected, but not unpredictable.